# PHP SNMP returns

Tags: php, snmp

I'm trying to retrieve OID's from my networkprinter HP M551. When I run the code I'm getting an error:

Error: Warning: snmpwalk(): No response from 10.100.68.21

Code:

```
<?php
    $a = snmpwalk("10.100.68.21", "public", ""); 
    foreach ($a as $val) {
        echo "$val\n";
    }
?>
```

The PHP-file is located on my webserver which is not located on my local network - could this be the error?
When I run a snmpwalk on my Linux machine on the network I get no errors.

Comment: Have you opened the nat-ports on your local router (if you are using a nat). Try to ping the HP from your internet server.

Comment: I'm sitting on a closed local network with very few possibilities in opening anything. Isn't there a way to use php on the local machine and not on the web-server?

Comment: In other words, having a php-script on my webserver on the wan, but running it on my LAN?

Comment: The solution might be a LAMP server on my LAN with a CRON job inserting data in the Webserver MySQL database and from there retrieving it to my webpage. It might be a Newb-solution. Any comments? L

Comment: For anyone interested it's not recommended to open a MySQL server to the public as all traffic is unencrypted and in plain text. I ended up, setting up a LAMP server and it works like a charm, though not being able to retrieve any data from outside og ny network.